# Setup two apache httpd sharing same load balancer

Tags: apache, load-balancing

I'm searching for a solution where i wan't to have the apache httpd web servers to share the loadbalancer state of each others. Is this even possible?

Basically, the setup i something like this (Tx = tomcat instance X)

```
     Hardware LB
        / \
   Httpd1  Httpd2
    / | \  / | \
  T1 T2  T3  T2 T1
```

Now, what i need is without clustering the tomcats (several different applications are hosted on them) 
have some sort of sharing between httpd1 and httpd2. 
Lets imagine that i have a balancer setup to something like this

```
<Proxy balancer://backendtomcats>
BalancerMember ajp://SERVER1:8009 loadfactor=1 route=jvm1000 connectiontimeout=10 timeout=160 retry=600 ttl=60 ping=1
BalancerMember ajp://SERVER1:9009 loadfactor=1 route=jvm1001 connectiontimeout=10 timeout=160 retry=600 ttl=60 ping=1 status=+H
BalancerMember ajp://SERVER2:8009 loadfactor=1 route=jvm2000 connectiontimeout=10 timeout=160 retry=600 ttl=60 ping=1 status=+H
BalancerMember ajp://SERVER2:9009 loadfactor=1 route=jvm2001 connectiontimeout=10 timeout=160 retry=600 ttl=60 ping=1 status=+H
BalancerMember ajp://SERVER3:8009 loadfactor=1 route=jvm2000 connectiontimeout=10 timeout=160 retry=600 ttl=60 ping=1 status=+H
BalancerMember ajp://SERVER3:9009 loadfactor=1 route=jvm2001 connectiontimeout=10 timeout=160 retry=600 ttl=60 ping=1 status=+H
```

The real problem lies in the fact that the backend application on balancer://backendtomcats must not be running on several instances at once, because it is having information in memory.

Is tomcat clustering the only option here(?) or:

Can the httpd share its loadbalancer status between two nodes? (some sort of webserver cluster)

Br M

Comment: You can go with this approach too. It won't be problem.

Comment: You mean, with same balancer setup on both apache?  I guCaIarantee that not two different instances will be getting requests simultaneously?

Comment: It would serve all instances as backend for Apache server to serve from various instances mentioned in Balancer. Looking at your question it seems that you want to have multiple tomcat to be served from frontend Apache; which can be served with above configuration. If there is anything other than this, please clarify so we can help.

Comment: Yeah, my question is that, if i have multiple (n>1) apache web servers, with hot standby mode(STATUS=+H), how can i know, that only one of the tomcat instances will get requests at the time?

Comment: You have hot standby mode configured on Apache to Tomcat however for your requirement you need to configure failover in Hardware load balancer